# Class Style not working on Django Template

Tags: css, django

I'm trying to color the background of readonly input text in my Django templates. I'm being brief in code because the only thing is not working is the color background.

I'm using the field 'rua' as the example. Maybe the problem is with the link of 'my own css' inside the base.html. This file is inside the same folder of the 'style.css':

[image]

My forms.py:

```
'rua': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly', 'id': 'rua', 'class': 'readonly'}),
```

My template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}


<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/master/src/jquery.mask.js"></script>

    <!-- customer login start -->
    <div class="customer_login">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <!--register area start-->
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 mx-auto">
                    <div class="account_form register">
                        {% if register_edit == 'register' %}
                        <p>{{ msg }}</p>
                        <h2>Não tem conta? Registre-se!</h2>
                        <form method="post" action="{% url 'account:register' %}">
                        {% else %}
                        <h2>Altere os dados da sua conta</h2>
                        <form method="post" action="{% url 'account:edit' %}">
                        {% endif %}

                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div>{{ user_form.as_p }}</div>

                            <div>{{ profile_form.as_p }}</div>


                            <p><button type="submit">Enviar</button></p>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--register area end-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- customer login end -->

<script src="{% static 'js/cadastro.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

My base.html

```
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Denise Andrade - Store</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static 'img/favicon.ico' %}">

    <!-- CSS
    ========================= -->

    <!-- Plugins CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/plugins.css' %}">

    <!-- Main Style CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">

    <!-- My Own Style CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/mystyle.css' %}">


    <!-- Os dados dentro do link 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js'
    do JQUERY do CardJS foram substituídos dentro do arquivo abaixo 'js/plugins.js'

    O arquivo 'js/plugins.js' é responsável por rodar o 'cart' na lateral
    -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/plugins.js' %}"></script>


</head>
```

My mystyle.css

```
// Backgroud color in disabled fields (rua, cidade, uf, etc) @ register page

.readonly{
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}
```

The funny thing is: if I insert the CSS code above inside the template, the code works perfectly. But trying to call 'mystyle.css' it does not work.

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: Have you opened your browser's console? Are there any 404 errors? Perhaps your css file is not loaded.

Comment: @rollingthedice, yes, there is a 404 error: "DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:8000/static/js/slinky.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE". But the file isn't the same I've mentioned in the post.